# PaaS Server - Random row order while using aggregate function with group by

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Result set of a query with an aggregate function and group by (no order by specified) returns different result or at least in different order almost in each execution.

I have a database on Azure PaaS server and it's behaving weirdly. The query in issue is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 "Org Unit", count(*) FROM "paas-server-12032019"."dbo"."testTable" GROUP BY "Org Unit"
```

When I check the "Org Unit" order, it's different each time. If I omit, count(*) and just keep the query as

```
SELECT TOP 100 "Org Unit" FROM "paas-server-12032019"."dbo"."testTable" GROUP BY "Org Unit"
```

It works as expected. Order of the record is consistent each time.
What I noticed

- It happened with a specific database, I have another one and in there it works as expected.
- Secondly, I think it has something to do when the column in group by is nvarchar(max)

I have a limited access currently to DB setup but wondering if there is anything that can cause this issue.

Any sort of help/discussion is deeply appreciated!

Comment: There is no guaranteed order if you do not specify an ORDER BY clause. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403).

Comment: @HandyD just wondering why the natural order (whatever the DB chooses) changes on each time I execute the same query!

Answer (score 1):

Without ORDER BY, you tell SQL Server that you don't care about the ordering.

SQL Server can do GROUP BY and aggregation internally by either sorting data or through hashing. SQL Server decides this based on what it expects to be the more efficient way. For your case when the order isn't consistent, SQL server found it more efficient to use hashing, apparently. You can see this in the execution plan.

Bottom line is, as always, if you want some specific order for the rows, then you need to use ORDER BY.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'll dive in into execution plan. But it still makes no sense, why it changes on each time I execute the query? In other term, why SQL server use different query plans each time I execute the same query?

Comment: Perhaps there are nuances in the hashing functions that varies between executions. AFAIK, the specs for the internal hashing function isn't documented, so all we have to go on is that we need an order by if we expect the rows in a certain order. Just as the specs for the language says. :-)